# Enter the user currently logged on to form

Tags: php, html, yii

I have this code

```
enter <div class="formularz">
    <div class="row">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'name')->label('Imię i nazwisko')?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'email')->label('Adres email') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'phone')->label('Telefon') ?>
        </div> here
```

How can i get in this inputs values of actualy logged user for example i  refresh page and i want to have filled inputs with some data.

Comment: if you're rendering this view from controller along with `model` value then you should automatically get all the values in your view, provided `name`, `email` & `phone` is in your db and they are not empty, if they are empty then the value will be blank.

Answer (score 1):

I take you're using `Yii`. Here is the documentation of what you're asking:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activeform.html#field%28%29-detail

Just add any attribute you want inside an array and plug it in as the third parameter of the `field` method.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'email',  ['inputOptions' => ['value' => 'my Value']])->label('Adres email') ?>
```

Comment: i try this but i have error Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveField::value

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, give it a try specifying the 'inputOptions'

Comment: but i have quesstion where i can use ['options' =>['style'=>'width: 525px']] becouse this defoult input have low width

Comment: Then add it to the array like this: ['value' => 'my Value', 'style'=>'width:525px']

Comment: @Informer Feel free to accept / upvote my answer if it was helpful to you.